# Combine D3.js with Tableau

Tags: iframe, d3.js, tableau-api

I want to include both d3.js and tableau in my program. Is it possible to include both of them into a single frame?

Comment: In what program? If you want to show d3 and tableau together you can embed a tableau visualisation along with a d3 visualisation on the same page. Looks like doing it with an iframe is popular. Here is a post that might help: http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2012/07/02/embedding-tableau-visualizations-on-the-web/comment-page-1/

Comment: Glad it worked, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you want to show `d3` and `tableau` together you can embed a tableau visualisation along with a d3 visualisation on the same page. [Looks like doing it with an iFrame is popular.](http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2012/07/02/embedding-tableau-visualizations-on-the-web/comment-page-1/)

Also, note that the way iFrames work with tableau have changed a bit over time, but here is the latest update (March 2014) from them: http://www.tableausoftware.com/public/blog/2014/03/fix-your-iframe-2386